# storyboard segue modal can't have back button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

So we built a bar button inside a popover and used a modal segue linked to a UIViewController in storyboard. However, there is not back button. How can we build a back button?

Comment: Just add a button and call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: but we want it at the navigation bar like the back tab button

Comment: You may add it there if you wish, just add a navigation item on the simulated metrics bar and will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, but note that [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] is deprecated since iOS6, now use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];